# How to deal with limits where the denominator tends to zero, and cancellation fails?

Tags: calculus, limits, rational-functions

If I have a function $f(x) = g(x)/h(x)$, where $g$ and $h$ are polynomial functions, and I want:

$ \lim_{x \to k} f(x)$, when $h(k) = 0$

Normally I would factor each one of the functions and cancel the 'zeroes' on the numerator with the ones in the denominator, e.g.:

$$
\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{x^2 + x - 6}{x^2 - 3x + 2} = \lim_{x \to 2} \frac{(x - 2)(x + 3)}{(x - 2)(x + 1)} = \lim_{x \to 2} \frac{x+3}{x+1} = 5/3
$$

My question is, if I can't cancel all the 'zeroes' in the denominator, can I say for sure that the limit does not exist? If not, then how can I find it?

Comment: you'd better give an example of which all the 'zeros' can't be canceled. There are diffrent cases.

Comment: You should factor $g(x)=g_1(x)(x-k)^{n}$ and $h(x)=h_1(x)(x-k)^m$, where $g_1(k)\neq 0$ and $h_1(k)\neq 0$. The it all boils down to the comparison of $n$ and $m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the **multiplicity** of the root $k$ :

You should be able to write $g(x) = (x-k)^N*\gamma(x)$ with $\gamma(k)\neq 0$

and $h(x) = (x-k)^M*\lambda(x)$ with $\lambda(k) \neq 0$.

M,N are positive integers (could be 0)

Basically the limit is the following :

- 0 if $N>M$
- $+\infty$ if $N<M$
- $\frac{\gamma(k)}{\lambda(k)}$ if $N=M$

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense! I was just thinking about he N = M case, and didn't know the other scenarios.

Comment: Well, actually, if N is the numerator, and M is the denominator, when N > M shouldn't if go to infinity, and go to 0 when N < M?

Comment: No, try with an example with multiplicity 2 and 1